# GET uncertain amount of request parameters with koa router

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, koa2, koa-router

if a define a route like this:

```js
router.get('/:name/:age', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = ctx.params
})
```

when i access the url: `http://localhost:3000/vortesnail/18`, I'll get:

```
{ 
  name: 'vortesnail',
  age: '18'
}
```

Here is my problem: if i access these urls, i want to get all params, what should i do with the `router.get('/name/age/????????', async () => {})`?

Example:

```js
http://localhost:3000/vortesnail/18/male
http://localhost:3000/vortesnail/18/male/student
http://localhost:3000/vortesnail/18/female
http://localhost:3000/vortesnail/18/female/student/any/any/any/....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute the parameters with a wildcard regex:

```js
const Koa = require("koa");
const Router = require("@koa/router");

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

router.get("/static-prefix/(.*)?", (ctx, next) => {
  console.log(ctx.params);
});

app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000);
```

Now if you open `http://localhost:3000/static-prefix/aa/bb/cc` it will print

`{ '0': 'aa/bb/cc' }`.

From here you can easily split/parse the individual parameters in javascript.